# Calculate segment of 3D line within distance from 3D triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, 3d, plane-geometry

Given an arbitrary 3D line (infinite length) and an arbitrary 3D triangle, how can I calculate which segment of the line (if any) is within a given distance d from the triangle?

Considerations:

- Will the same method work whether the line intersects the triangle or not?
- In the intersection case, what if it intersects along a line? (i.e. the line lies on the plane of the triangle)
- If the calculation is expensive, are there any quick checks to see if there's a result at all? (i.e. skip the expensive part if it's "obvious" no part of the line is within the given distance)

I've tried imagining the line as a cylinder of radius d but that doesn't actually help me as I also don't know how to solve the problem of cylinder/triangle intersection. I've also thought about "flattening" the line into the triangle's plane to turn it into a 2D problem but I have a lot of trouble conceptualising its relation back to the 3D problem.

Comment: Is that a solid triangle or just the three line segments? It makes a difference when $d$ is enough smaller than the triangle. To *see* it, draw circles of radius $d$ about each vertex, then find the three common tangents on the outsides of those circles, drawing on the segments between the points of tangency. Remove the parts of the circles inside those lines. The result will be a larger similar triangle, but with its corners all rounded off. The segment is determined by where the line interstects that shape. This gives you hints on how to calculate it as well.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I suppose it would be that shape except as a solid where the circles are instead spheres and the top/bottom face are the shared tangent planes, I'm not sure if that's useful though as it seems like a more complicated approach than say representing the line as a cylinder (of radius d)

Comment: You are right that I forgot it was 3D (despite your making it very clear). The difference between my visualization and yours is that you are asking for a particular segment on the line. For my description, the segment is between the two intersections of the line with the convex surface described. Yours will tell you if the line is within $d$ of any part of the triangle, but does not identify the segment.